# Protobuf, OSX, ant compilation error

Tags: macos, ant, protocol-buffers, dylib

I use a protobuf project compiled with Ant. The `proto` files are shared via SVN, and they are locally compiled to Java classes using:

```
ant protobuf
```

I've recently upgraded OSX Mountain Lion. When one of the `proto` files has changed, I've got this error when building:

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.6.dylib
```

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I've copied the entire folder, with the binaries, from my old drive.

**The only solution that worked was deleting the repo locally, and checking it out again.** After the checkout was complete, I've rebuilt with `ant protobuf`. It built all the libraries from scratch (~2 minutes), reinstalled the library and compiled the `proto` files without errors.